# Using seaborn barplot to plot wide-form dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, grouped-bar-chart

I'm trying to produce a bar chart with all the observations in my `DataFrame`, which looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {0: [52, 52, 52, 45, 0, 0],
        1: [49, 52, 52, 0, 0, 0],
        2: [48, 52, 52, 41, 0, 0]}

# (rows = years, columns = objects, values = violations of object in year)
cluster_yearly_results_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    0   1   2
0  52  49  48
1  52  52  52
2  52  52  52
3  45   0  41
4   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
```

I'm getting the right type of graph when using the default pandas `plot`:

```
cluster_yearly_results_df.plot.bar()
```

[image]

However, I would like to use seaborn, and I am having trouble inputting wide-form dataframes, using:

```
sns.barplot(data=cluster_yearly_results_df)
```

Can I use seaborn for what I want to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) docs say:

> A bar plot represents an estimate of central tendency for a numeric variable with the height of each rectangle and provides some indication of the uncertainty around that estimate using error bars.

In other words, the purpose is to represent multiple values for a one variable with a single bar that represents the `mean`, and error bars for `std`. You are looking to represent individual values with bars as the [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) does.

Having said this, you can tweak your `DataFrame` as below to match the `seaborn` interface. Starting with a `DataFrame` similar to yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

   A  B  C
0  7  6  4
1  3  5  9
2  3  0  5
3  0  1  3
4  9  7  7
```

Use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to create two columns that uniquely identify each value in `y`:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['x', 'hue', 'y']
```

which yields:

```
   x hue  y
0  0   A  6
1  0   B  1
2  0   C  2
3  1   A  5
4  1   B  7
```

then plot:

```
sns.barplot(y='y', x='x', hue='hue', data=df)
```

[image]